# Run HTML Code upon Button onclick

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a piece of HTML code for a particular item for sale on a website.  This code has all of the information needed for the item, including title, price, dimensions, weight, etc.  It also has an "Add To Cart" button included with it.

What I want to do is turn away from Wix and hand-code the entire website using HTML5, CSS3, and Bootstrap 4.1.1.  I want to use the same HTML code snippet that I included in Wix, but without the button.  I will create my own Bootstrap button.

My question is how do I make it so the code runs when the bootstrap button is clicked?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have played around with the general layout of the site, but nothing in regards to the button.  Here is what the original website looks like, and you will notice the "Add To Cart" button, the two radio buttons, and the text box.  That whole thing is what is created by the HTML wizard that my shopping cart service provided me.  https://www.nationalparkmysteries.com/books

Comment: The HTML code I speak of does not show up in Firefox for some reason.  It does work in Chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is JavaScript.  Not to split hairs, but HTML is technically not code; it's considered "markup."  To get dynamic information, you have to use JavaScript.  This might require more conplexity than you realize.

```
var containerElement = document.querySelector('.container');
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('.button');
var populateContainer = function() {
  // do some stuff here
}
buttonElement.onclick = populateContainer;
```

You may also need some knowledge of a back end language, like PHP, to help you build your shop.  For a beginner, I would recommend looking into WordPress so you could install a plugin that handles that stuff for you, like WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

Would need more details on what exactly you're trying to do, but Javascript/jQuery is a great way to dynamically make links when a button is clicked.

Assuming you have inputs from the user to get certain product attributes (color/size/etc). You would make it so that when a button is clicked, the jQuery code would check each input and stitch together a URL for you.